# How to start with a new GItHub repository

Tags: github

I made several attempts, and you could see on the screenshots

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWSIs.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZa2d.png]

[image]

How can I start with my GitHub repository?

Comment: What do yoy want to do? What do mean by "tune"? Also there is a Russian StackOverflow https://ru.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

"Как настроить" is not exactly "tune", but "start working with", as in set up.

All you need to do is to clone that GitHub repo locally, add some files, commit and push back, [as seen here](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/).

If you need to use [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/), you can follow "[Cloning a repository from GitHub to GitHub Desktop](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing-to-projects/cloning-a-repository-from-github-to-github-desktop/)"